# Creating range of weights

Tags: python

I'm building a portfolio optimizer in Python. I have an array with different stock parameters and what I need to do is figure out which weights I need to assign to each stock in order to find the optimal performance of the portfolio.

The way I'm doing it right now is by creating N nested loops (with N being the number of stocks in the array) where each loop ranges from 0 to 1 in .1 increments and before executing the code in the body of the loop I evaluate whether the sum of the weights is equal to 1; otherwise the loop continues without executing the code.

For instance, if I have an array consisting of two stocks ["A","B"], I will create two nested loops ranging from 0 to 1 in .1 increments, and calculating the performance of the portfolio with those weights inside the body of the loops, returning the weights that provide optimal performance. I'm aware this approach is very inefficient for two main reasons:

1- I am doing more iterations than necessary since I'm only interested in solutions where the weigths add up to 1.

2- As the number of stocks in my portfolio increases, so does the number of nested loops and therefore the time required to execute the code increases exponentially. This limits the amount of stocks I can evaluate in a realistic time frame with the computational power I have available.

I know there has to be a way of doing this way more efficiently. This might be a very basic question but I just can't think of a way of doing it. Hopefully I have explained my problem clearly enough.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

optimal_performance = 0
    
stocks = ["A","B"]

def test_range():
    weight_scale = np.linspace(0,1,int(1/0.01)+1)
    
    for i in weight_scale:
        yield i

for weights in product(test_range(), repeat=len(stocks)):
    if sum(weights) == 1:
        # Here I calculate the performance of the portfolio with the given weights
        if performance > optimal_performance:
            optimal_performance = performance
```

Comment: Could you please give an example by code?

Comment: You only need one loop for the first weight. The second one is `1 - first_weight`. This eliminates your first problem

Comment: I am not an expert (never worked with) but you can look into [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html). The way I see it, you have a set of two equations: `aA + bB + cC + ... = X` and `a + b + c + ... = 1` and you want to maximize `X`

Comment: Agree with @Tomerikoo, portfolio optimization is just using optimization method to find the best solution. However, of course, to use `scipy.optimize` , you need a quadratic equation (as portfolio optimization uses it) and initial vector of length n, as well as your mean return vector and covariance matrix

Comment: Thanks everyone, what Khanzadeh_AH proposed works, but still takes too long. I've tried using the scipy.optimization package and although it was a bit confusing at first, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `n` stocks you need to find all the combinations of weight_scale that have `n` members. Then filter those combinations and choose those ones that their members sum up to `1`. Then you can find all the permutations for these weight combinations.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, permutations

optimal_performance = 0
    
stocks = ["A","B"]

weight_scale = np.linspace(0,1,int(1/0.01)+1)
weight_combinations = combinations(weight_scale, len(stocks))
valid_weight_combinations = filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 1, weight_combinations)
all_permutations = [list(permutations(w)) for w in valid_weight_combinations]
```

for `2` stocks, all_permutations is like below:

```
[[(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)], [(0.01, 0.99), (0.99, 0.01)], [(0.02, 0.98), (0.98, 0.02)], [(0.03, 0.97), (0.97, 0.03)], [(0.04, 0.96), (0.96, 0.04)], [(0.05, 0.9500000000000001), (0.9500000000000001, 0.05)], [(0.06, 0.9400000000000001), (0.9400000000000001, 0.06)], [(0.07, 0.93), (0.93, 0.07)], [(0.08, 0.92), (0.92, 0.08)], [(0.09, 0.91), (0.91, 0.09)], [(0.1, 0.9), (0.9, 0.1)], [(0.11, 0.89), (0.89, 0.11)], [(0.12, 0.88), (0.88, 0.12)], [(0.13, 0.87), (0.87, 0.13)], [(0.14, 0.86), (0.86, 0.14)], [(0.15, 0.85), (0.85, 0.15)], [(0.16, 0.84), (0.84, 0.16)], [(0.17, 0.8300000000000001), (0.8300000000000001, 0.17)], [(0.18, 0.8200000000000001), (0.8200000000000001, 0.18)], [(0.19, 0.81), (0.81, 0.19)], [(0.2, 0.8), (0.8, 0.2)], [(0.21, 0.79), (0.79, 0.21)], [(0.22, 0.78), (0.78, 0.22)], [(0.23, 0.77), (0.77, 0.23)], [(0.24, 0.76), (0.76, 0.24)], [(0.25, 0.75), (0.75, 0.25)], [(0.26, 0.74), (0.74, 0.26)], [(0.27, 0.73), (0.73, 0.27)], [(0.28, 0.72), (0.72, 0.28)], [(0.29, 0.71), (0.71, 0.29)], [(0.3, 0.7000000000000001), (0.7000000000000001, 0.3)], [(0.31, 0.6900000000000001), (0.6900000000000001, 0.31)], [(0.32, 0.68), (0.68, 0.32)], [(0.33, 0.67), (0.67, 0.33)], [(0.34, 0.66), (0.66, 0.34)], [(0.35000000000000003, 0.65), (0.65, 0.35000000000000003)], [(0.36, 0.64), (0.64, 0.36)], [(0.37, 0.63), (0.63, 0.37)], [(0.38, 0.62), (0.62, 0.38)], [(0.39, 0.61), (0.61, 0.39)], [(0.4, 0.6), (0.6, 0.4)], [(0.41000000000000003, 0.59), (0.59, 0.41000000000000003)], [(0.42, 0.58), (0.58, 0.42)], [(0.43, 0.5700000000000001), (0.5700000000000001, 0.43)], [(0.44, 0.56), (0.56, 0.44)], [(0.45, 0.55), (0.55, 0.45)], [(0.46, 0.54), (0.54, 0.46)], [(0.47000000000000003, 0.53), (0.53, 0.47000000000000003)], [(0.48, 0.52), (0.52, 0.48)], [(0.49, 0.51), (0.51, 0.49)]]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, what Khanzadeh_AH proposed works, but still takes too long. I've tried using the scipy.optimization package and although it was a bit confusing at first, worked perfectly.